# How install and use scalaj-http

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an assignment to use some http client. I am planning to use scalaj-http for that. The installation page for that https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http, it says:

Installation
in your build.sbt

libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.4"

But nothing is clearly mention, where do i need to do and what needs to be done? Is it command, or we have to paste this somewhere.

Can someone explain in detail?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an SBT project and add that library dependency in your build file. This link should help you to get started: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html

Comment: I didn't get what to do. What i did was, added that dependency line in build.sbt of project. Do i need to import this project now?

Comment: Did you create an SBT project as mentioned in the link ? Were you able to run Hello World project ? If yes, then add the dependency of scalaj-http library and then try to reload, clean and compile the project using `sbt reload clean compile`. Run Hello World again. If it worked, you are good to go! If you want to use an IDE, then you can import the project (but make sure you have the related IDE plugin). You don't need to import anything otherwise.